# Can one use 3D geometry classes from .NET PresentationCore in a .Net Core class library project?

Tags: .net-core

I do not have much experience with .NET Core. My current project is a .NET Core (5.0) class library in which I would like to use classes like Point3D, Vector3D from Windows.Media.Media3D (PresentationCore) (as shown in the picture).

[image]

However, when I try to add a reference to that framework, nothing happens. Neither does anything happen if I try to add something in the Dependencies / Frameworks node of Solution Explorer - it seems to be impossible.

Is there any possibility to solve this? Alternatively, I would have to program all the code about points and vectors myself which does not make much sense if there exists a ready to use product.

Comment: Not sure why it's behaving that way. But I believe PresentationCore is a WPF library. You don't want to include Windows-specific GUI code in a .NET Core class library, even if you could. I suggest you just Google for another vector math library for Core.

Comment: Hi Noah, and thanks. Yes, PresentationCore IS WPF. It was no problem to include it into a .Net Framework project, but with Core it seemingly does not function. While waiting for an answer I wrote these simple classes myself.

Comment: I doubt if this is possible.